# Dynamic Light Scattering

Tags: statistics, average, correlation

In DLS does the combination of the Time Average and Ensemble Average give a better statistical average than the results shown by each case considered separately ?

Comment: (a) What is DLS or Dynamic Light Scattering? (b) What is the "time average" and "ensemble average" in this context? (c) Is your question perhaps a better fit for our sister site http://stats.stackexchange.com ?